# ASP.NET MVC - Razor and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, razor

How can I put javascript inside `if` block?

```
@if(TempData["notification-message"] != null) {
        $('#notification').jnotifyAddMessage({
            text: '@TempData["notification-message"]',
                permanent: false
                            });
}
```

I'm getting `bad compile constant value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$` sign does not signal Razor to switch to Html mode.

Place the script wrapped in`<text>` tags:

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((TempData["notification-message"] as string))) {
     <text>
        $('#notification').jnotifyAddMessage({
            text: '@TempData["notification-message"].ToString(),
                permanent: false
                            });
     </text>
}
```